# Disable image selection in grouped Microsoft Word form

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

A Word 365 form includes a logo image and content controls. To protect it from editing, I selected all and used Developer > Group > Group. The form works fine. The protection works fine.

**ISSUE:** If a user clicks the logo image, resize handles are displayed. Because the image is protected, users can't move or change it, but the handles are confusing to some. Is there a way to disable *selection* of a protected image?

I would have expected disabling in a protected region to be default behavior.

I have tried protecting the form using Restrict Editing. Same issue.

Comment: I tried putting the image inside a Picture Content Control and setting the properties of that control to not allow deletion nor editing. This did not work. Still allowed selection. I would suggest sending feedback to MS. https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11